# Cannot parse strings correctly to remove special characters

Tags: python, pandas

I have one column of a df, which contains strings, which I wish to parse:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':'apple banana orange'.split(), 'size':"2'20 12:00 456".split()})
```

which gives
[image]

I wish to remove all ' characters, remove :\d\d and preserve the pure integers, such that the results looks like as follows:

[image]

I have tried to extract the integers prior to ':' and filling the NaN with the original data. While this works for the first row (preserving the original data) and for the second row (correctly removes the ' character), for the last row it somehow casts the data of the first row. My code is

`df['size'] = df['size'].str.extract('(\d*):').fillna(df['size'])`

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to filter this data before you create the dataframe?

Comment: Why does `2'20` become `220` but `12:00` becomes `12` and not `1200`?

Comment: Maybe `df['size'] = df['size'].str.replace(r"'", '').str.replace(r'((\d{2}):\d{2})', r'\2', regex=True)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need to test for the `'` and the `:` in the time stamp this will do the job:

```
df["size"] = df["size"].str.replace("'", "").str.split(":").map(lambda x: x[0])
```

Output:

```
     name size
0   apple  220
1  banana   12
2  orange  456
```

Comment: Thanks @Henrik Bo. That works! I understand the str.replace, but why does str.split(":") remove the digits trailing the ":" only? And, what does the .map (lambda) part do?

Comment: @Prolle the str.split divide a string into a list where ":" separate the list elements. Try to remove the ".map(lambda x: x[0])" and check the output. Then you will understand. I then only takes the first element [0] of the list with the lambda function.

Comment: Ah, I got it, very good, thank you Henrik

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I am wrong, but can't you do `.replace('character', '')`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
df['size'] = df['size'].str.replace(r"'", '').str.replace(r'((\d{2}):\d{2})', r'\2', regex=True)
```

Outputs:

```
    name    size
0   apple   220
1   banana  12
2   orange  456
```